# Why OneNote show files in Chrome icon?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I save my notebook on OneNote and the icon of the project is Chrome icon and when I click it it opens the project online rather than in my PC. How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you save the project? OneNote notebooks will be not be saved locally unless you export them manually, but then you create a local copy that will not sync.

Comment: I save in OneDrive

Comment: Do you see the icon in Explorer?